# Irreducible unitary representation with a $G$-invariant dense linear subspace

Tags: representation-theory

Is there a group $G$ with a unitary irreducible representation on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and  a proper dense $G$-invariant linear subspace $V\subset\mathcal{H}$?

(note that the existence of such $V$ does not contradict irreducibility of $\mathcal{H}$ since $V$ is necessarily not closed)